# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError in c++ dll

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have used JNI to call a simple hello world function.

`JAVA File`

```
public class HelloJNI {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }
    private native void sayHello();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloJNI().sayHello();
    }
}
```

I have the `hello.dll` file in the same directory.

I have even added the directory to the `PATH` variable.

Still not working.

Thanks in advance.

Error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: HelloJNI.sayHello()V
        at HelloJNI.sayHello(Native Method)
        at HelloJNI.main(HelloJNI.java:9)`

The C++ file:

```
#include "jni.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "HelloJNI.h"
using namespace std;

// Implementation of native method sayHello() of HelloJNI class
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj){
cout << "Hello World from C++!" << endl;
return;
}
```

The header file:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include "jni.h"
/* Header for class HelloJNI */

#ifndef _Included_HelloJNI
#define _Included_HelloJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
* Class:     HelloJNI
* Method:    sayHello
* Signature: ()V
*/
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello
(JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full Stack Trace? :)

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: And the C code? And the. h file?

Comment: I have added those files too @EJP

Comment: Could it be that you have another "hello.dll" in a directory on the PATH variable that is found instead of the one you want?

Comment: The library must be in java.library.path or this must be passed to the JVM as an argument (-Djava.library.path=<library path>).  Try the latter and see if it helps

Comment: @V3V If that was the problem the error would have been thrown at the `loadLibrary()` stage, and wouldn't have details of a specific method. The question here is whether the actual DLL really contains the code that is posted here.

Comment: I compiled the code and generated the dll. I think there is no error in the dll. @EJP

Comment: To make sure check with Dependency Walker, if the required export is there.

Comment: @Gokul It doesn't matter what you think, it matters what Java thinks, and it doesn't agree with you. If there was no error in the DLL you wouldn't have a problem and you wouldn't be posting here.

Comment: Thank u guys... I got the solution... The method in which I generate the dll was the actual problem...